# MLE of exponential distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I have to find the MLE where I'm given a Random variable Y with density function

$f(y|t) = e^{-(y-t)}$, when $y \geq t$ and $f(y|t) = 0$ otherwise. Assume that $t$ is unknown and a random sample $(Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n)$ on Y is given.

**My attempt**:

I have defined the likelihood function as:

$L(t) = e^{-(y_1 + y_2 + ...+ y_n - nt)}$

Then I have taken the derivative with respect to t and got:

$L(t)' = n e^{nt - y_1 - y_2 - ... - y_n}$

Then I have set it equal to zero to find maximum. Then the only solution would be if $n = 0$. But does this makes sense? Shouldn't it be $t$ that I should find a solution for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bidding factor in the likelihood function:

$$L(\mathbf{y}|t)=\prod^n_{j=1}e^{t-y_j}\mathbb{1}_{[t,\infty)}(y_j)=e^{nt-\sum^n_{j=1}y_j}\mathbb{1}(t\leq y_{(1)})$$
where $y_{(1)}=\min_{1\leq j]\leq n}y_j$. Notice that as a function of $t$, $L$ is positive and monotone increasing over $(-\infty,y_{(1)}]$ and $0$ on $(y_{(1)},\infty)$. Thus $L$ achieves a maximum value when $t=y_{(i)}$, i.e., the MLE of parameter $t$ is $Y_{(1)}$.